# Raster Layer in QGIS - nightlights data not loading

Tags: qgis, symbology

Using QGIS, I want to load the nightlights data available on `https://eogdata.mines.edu/download_dnb_composites.html`. My output is an all black screen with numbers shown on the bottom left in the Layers section.

I have tried changing the symbology to all Reds palette but the output is one colour throughout only.

I am not sure what is the problem. Can someone suggest what to do?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you edit your post and indicate what you've actually done - have you downloaded and added a GeoTIFF? Using which QGIS version?

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I have downloaded and added a GeoTIFF. I am using the qgis version 3.14.16. This is the name of the application - "QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.14.16-2-Setup-x86_64"

Answer (score 2):

The data you're loading range from -0.6 to >2,000 but most urban areas have light values between around 1 and 8. You need to adjust the symbology to display a range of colours for those low numbers otherwise you'll see an area almost all one colour.

[image]

Using a grayscale white-to-black colour ramp, inverted, and choosing a 'middle' value around the light value of urban areas:

[image]

Now features appear:

[image]

Experimenting with different levels and colours and zooming in to the subcontinent:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. While my interface is a little different, i was nevertheless able to tweak the options and obtain an image worthwhile

Comment: I have a related query. I want to access this data possibly in the R software for further project work. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Comment: Best to ask a new question, after attempting to solve it so you can share your code. If this answer was helpful please indicate it as solved.